# how to call a C# .NET web service from a php client

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, web-services

I have a Hello World c# ASP .NET web service which is automatically generated by visual studio  web service project. I want to call it from a php client. Can I know how to do it? Better if anyone can provide with small code example.. I dont have much experience in php and no in depth understanding of web services so finding difficult to do this..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since PHP is a dynamic language, its pretty straight forward.  All you need is a library (SoapUI) and the WSDL.  If you have the location (URL) of the web service add a ?WSDL to the end of the URL and you have the definition.  Then its just calling the service from there.

```
<?php
require_once('libs/nusoap.php');
$wsdl="http://thedomain.com/theservice/endpoing.svc?wsdl";
$client=new soapclient($wsdl, 'wsdl');
$param=array('number1'=>'2', 'number2'=>'3');
echo $client->call('add', $param);
?>
```

You can find the library here: http://www.soapui.org/

Comment: thanks. I have the url of the web service and I installed soapui as well. Can I know what did you mean by require_once('libs/nusoap.php') ?
It can't find the path 'libs/nusoap.php' and gives the following error.

Failed opening required 'libs/nusoap.php' (include_path='.;C:\php5\pear') in C:\wamp\www\hello.php on line 6

Comment: I got it. I m  using nusoap as the soap client library. I tried to call the HelloWorld method of the web service using following:

                require_once('lib/nusoap.php');
  $wsdl="http://localhost:64226/Service1.asmx?wsdl";
  $client=new soapclient($wsdl, 'wsdl');  
  echo $client->call('HelloWorld');

But it does not return the output "Hello World". Instead prints the word "Array". Any idea ? I know this must be a very basic question i m asking :)

Comment: Sorry, I'm used to PHP4, so an even better solution for you if you have PHP5 is to use the built in SoapClient.  Example code (tested) runs like so:
[PHP Client]
<?php
class SayHello {
   public $name = 'Benny';
}

$client = new SoapClient('http://localhost/WebService1/Service1.asmx?wsdl');
$result = $client->SayHello(new SayHello());

echo $result->SayHelloResult;
?>

[ASMX Service]
[WebMethod]
public string SayHello(String name)
{
   return "Hello " + name;
}

Comment: thanks a lot Benny! It worked for me using SoapClient in php 5. 
Initially I got an error saying it is undefined and then I realized that I had not enabled php_soap extension in WAMP. After enabling it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's a SOAP web service, you *should* just be able to use the normal [php SOAP library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php). Now SOAP portability isn't quite everything it's cracked up to be in my experience, so you may need to fiddle a bit (in particular, test things like how empty arrays work) but that should be a good starting point.

The docs I've linked to look pretty good, but if you search for "php SOAP tutorial" you get lots of hits which will take you through step-by-step.

Another option is [nusoap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/). I can't comment on which implementation is better.

Comment: Thanks. I thought of using nusoap